# Typedef for reference types in C#?

Tags: c#

Does C# have a typedef for reference types? I know that there's a `using TypeName = RealType`, but does that take effect across multiple files, or just the local scope?

**Edit**: If it's just in the current file, is there a way to make it global?

Comment: (nullable reference types is redundant, btw; reference types are always nullable)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: actually there is "global::" to put a type in the global namespace.  See my answer below.

Comment: For clarity, global:: is not a typedef obviously.  I brought it up because I have found it useful in situations where typedefs are also useful.  An example would be a 3rd party lib that does something dumb like use the same name or namespace as a clr type, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just in the current file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no global typedef in C#.  The closest you can get is subclassing.  For instance, you might use it to clean up a complicated generic:

```
public class FunctionLookups : Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Func<string, bool>>> {}
```

Comment: Does this make the code difficult to work with? I've heard that in Java doing this is bad, although I can't remember why.

Comment: It is bad because you can't actually substitute instances of the base for the derived.  Even casting will fail.  But they are actually the same thing, they just have a different name.

Comment: Constructors are not inherited, so your solution requires to override all (required) constructors.

Comment: Yeah, it is bad.  You can run into troubles.  It is NOT a typecast... just the closest thing.